# Как сохранить соотношение сторон разных графиков

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть 4 разных графика расположенных на subplots, как мне сохранить соотношение сторон?
По высоте они одинаковые(0.3), но по ширине есть 0.1 и 0.2, но 0.1 растягивается до 0.2, можно ли как-то сделать чтобы графики масштабировались между собой, как по высоте, так и по ширине?

Comment: Можно `xlim` задать попробовать. Ну и `shareX=True` тоже попробовать, я не помню как оно действует.

Comment: @CrazyElf sharex пробовал не срабатывает, оно наоборот уменьшает 0.2 к 0.1, у меня такое чувство, что график растягивается на все свободное выделенное место под него. Может Вы знаете как это отключить?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас известно количество холстов и их соотношение, то можно сделать просто, через subplot_mosaic:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    '''
    AAB
    CCD
    '''
    ,figsize=(3, 5), constrained_layout=True)


for ax in axs.values():
    ax.plot(list(range(20)))
    
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что между тройными кавычками задет расположение холстов (axes). Одинакаовые буквы подряд - один холст. То есть, "AA" это первый холст, "B" - второй. Поскольку букв в обозначении первого холста в 2 раза больше, то и холст в два раза длиннее по ширине. Так же можно компоновать и по высоте.

Comment: Но у Вас не сохраняется масштаб между осями, у меня оси будут неизвестных мне размеров, допустим по oY у меня будет 0.5 у всех графиков, но oX разные, и у какого-то графика oX 0.2 и мне нужно чтобы длина этой оси была 2/5 от длина oY, если 0.3, то 3/5 и тд. Я хочу чтобы длина оси у отдельного графика была относительно максимальной оси из всех графиков, наверное так еще можно выразиться.

Comment: У меня примерные графики. смотрите на соотношения в определении самой мозаики. я вам привел способ отобразить графики так, как вам надо. почитайте, в конце концов, про этот метод документацию. Или про grid_spec.